# MVC3 asp.net Html.AntiForgeryToken() issue while user having multiple tabs with same form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

I am attempting to add the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the login form of a MVC3 site. This form is on every page of the site. I have noticed that if the user opens multiple tabs on the site, and then goes back to an old tab and submits the login form, the tokens on the other tabs become invalid, even when using salt. Is there any way to work around this?

This is just one example, there are other forms on the site that users seem to be opening multiple tabs to.

Answer (score -1):

We have same issue on our e-commerce websites.
In my situation user can put things to his basket without logging in. But after opening several tabs without logging in, user decides to login and tries to add all products after logging in in one tab and that's where error lies.

So I decided to put a get on this pages just before submitting the form to get a new AntiForgeryToken.

I created a new partial view with only Html.AntiForgeryToekn in it and calling it via AJAX before submitting the form. And replace __RequestVarificationToekn value on form with the new one.

I Hope this solves the issue for you.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using FormsAuthentication to login? If yes then the same token instance is being shared across multiple tabs while logging in, and hence all users with existing cookies will run into trouble. To work around this, please follow this post for further help

[MVC-ANTIFORGERY-TOKEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421962/asp-net-mvc3-antiforgerytoken)